# Unable to resize image in html (cshtml asp.net mvc 4)

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Unable to resize image: when I change *height* attribute nothing happens (even if I remove it) but the image size only reacts when *width* changes (both width and height are changed). Here is the line (razor view, asp.net mvc 4, html5):

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")" />
```

**Questions:**
1) What can be the reason for such behavior?
2) How to resize image so that it will not go out of a particular scope (e.g. width 150 and height 150). I have images of different sizes and I want them to be of identical size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use class or style?

`<img src="" alt="" class="yourclass" />`
`<img src="" alt="" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" />`